# Button Element Css Keeps on resizing when moving to different screen

Tags: css, button, element

So i am working on putting a button in my application website. The thing is that the button css element keeps on resizing when i switch screen and i want it to stay like my other elements as well.
Here is my Button code in Home.Js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import HeroSection from '../../HeroSection';
import { homeObjOne, homeObjTwo, homeObjThree } from './Data';
import './Home.css';


function Home() {
  
  return (
    <>
      <HeroSection {...homeObjOne} />
      <Link to="/Sign-up">
     <button className="button" type="button">
          Sign In or Register Today!
     </button>
 </Link>
      <HeroSection {...homeObjThree} />
      <HeroSection {...homeObjTwo} />
      
    </>
    
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Here is my Home.css file

```
  .button {
    padding: 12px 64px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid var(--primary);
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-size: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    position: absolute;
    left: 18.4%;
    bottom: 450px;
  }
.button:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #278087;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  }
```

I have tried putting position:absolute and position:relative but still causes the same issue and couldn't figure out why it keeps happening.

Comment: What do you mean by "switching a screen"?

Comment: I don't want my element to resize or move to a different direction when i switch to a different screen/monitor

Comment: Tell your problem more clearly (send a screenshot,...)